# Topological Indistinguishability questions

Tags: general-topology

When proving that two points in a topological space are indistinguishable, is it enough to show that they have the same open neighborhoods? Or, would I have to prove it for both open and closed neighborhoods. It seems to me that showing two elements appear as pairs for all open neighborhoods is enough and that maybe it can be implied that it holds true for neighborhoods in general.

Comment: Where did you find this concept? I have never encountered it in Munkres at least

Comment: You only need the open neighborhoods.

Comment: [I think wiki answers well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_indistinguishability#:~:text=In%20a%20pseudometric%20space%2C%20two,x%20%E2%88%92%20y%E2%80%96%20%3D%200.)

Comment: @Beautifullyirrational There's someone on youtube with a topology series who talked about this concept. He always described it as "drawing lines" between elements, but after some research I discovered the technical terminology is indistinguishability

Comment: Next time I suggest mentioning the source @AdamS

Comment: @Beautifullyirrational Ok will do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

For $x \in X$ let $\mathcal O(x)$ and $\mathcal N(x)$ denote the sets of all open neighborhoods and all neigborhoods of $x$, respectively. Clearly $\mathcal O(x) \subset \mathcal N(x)$, but in general $\mathcal O(x) \ne \mathcal N(x)$.

Now assume that $x,y \in X$ such that $\mathcal O(x) = \mathcal O(y)$. We prove that $\mathcal N(x) = \mathcal N(y)$.

So let $N \in \mathcal N(x)$. This means that there is an $U \in \mathcal O(x)$ such that $x \in U \subset N$. By assumption  $y \in U$, thus $y \in N$, i.e. $N \in \mathcal N(y)$. Similarly $N \in \mathcal N(y)$ implies $N \in \mathcal N(x)$.